# Screen blinking when removing queries in React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am currently using TanStack React Query to make an UI and I have an issue when I invoke `queryClient.removeQueries(queryKey)` clicking on a button.

The issue is that every click I do, the display flickers once. The cache is correctly cleaned but the flicker is annoying.

Is this a normal behaviour? I would like to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add a  photo or provide more info?

Comment: why are you removing a query while it is on screen? What behaviour would you expect? This question needs more context please

Comment: I have some buttons in a screen. When I click on any of them, I get some data and I render it. Every time I click another button, while data is fetching, I need to clear rendered data of the screen.
Anyway, I have solved the issue using `queryClient.setQueryData([queryKey], '')` instead of `queryClient.removeQueries(queryKey)`